# Drawing affine cone on overleaf

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I do not have that much experience with plotting in LaTex and have no idea how/where to start plotting the following image:[image]

I would really appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Se! What you try yourself? Where you stuck? Drawing of an image is independent from Overleaf, it is youst editor. See https://texample.net// if there is is some similar image.